# Ms Access with a linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have MS Access which is linked to SQL Server

I'm typing on a keyboard with Kurdish Central layout.

Data in SQL Server is no problem, but in MS Access it's showing a column as

```
#Deleted
```

This problem is only in Kurdish.

What is the solution to this problem?

Thanks for everything ...

[image]

[image: Blockquote]

Comment: try reading this and see if it applies  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/access-linked-table-deleted

Comment: @DougCoats   

Any tutorial videos please?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the CREATE TABLE statement for your table, and the name + version of the ODBC driver you are using to link the table. -- Try the [Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) if you're using an older one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has ANY relevance in regards to the language used.

Make sure the server table has a PK id, and also add a row version column to the sql server table. (row version is called timestamp - but has ZERO to do with time - worlds worst name in history for a column type in sql server).

So, ensure the sql table has a PK column defined, and also that timestamp column. Now, rel-link the access table and try again.

Comment: column ID PK It's okay with the table I've laid out nicely
But
if type keyboard English or arabic Iraq no prblem 
But if typing by keyboard ((  Kurdish Central ))
after Linked to sql server or mysql    add data to table error all row equal #DELETED...

Comment: And you added a timestamp column? (I suggested you ensure and have both a pk and also added a timestamp (row version) column. It's really hard to give advice when you choose to ignore advice. Do you like and enjoy wasting my time?  And consider installing the native 17 or 18 odbc driver and link tables using newer odbc drivers.

Comment: I think a character (or characters) produced by your Kurdish keyboard is not supported by a module in the chain: form/datasheet/MsAccess/connectivity libraries/SQL Server. The typed character is sent to the server and presumably accepted (you get no errors); then MsAccess reads it back from SQL Server using the key information, to confirm the update (and refresh any other columns), and it can't find it. Normally if you declared an integer primary key (we can't see if you have done so on the screen-shots) translation problem shouldn't occur.

Comment: It's possible that language and region settings are the issue here, but trying upgraded odbc drivers and adding a timestamp to the table might well fix this. Standard fair to have both pk and timestamp columns and we OFTEN get and see deleted when using access with default USA language settings. So we at least want to eliminate the basic setup and try my suggestions before we conclude that language and region settings are the issue here. But then again I can't help unless these things are attempted and suggestions are followed